# Generic stack push error

Tags: c, data-structures, void-pointers, memmove

Im trying to create a generic stack. I have a problem when i try to push a value
into the stack, the programm crashes in the memmove line:

```
typedef struct s_node{
    void *info;
    struct s_node *next;
}t_node;

typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    int salary;
}t_employee;

typedef t_node* t_stack;

void createStack(t_stack *p){
    *p=NULL;
}

int push(t_stack *p,void *inf,int siz){
    t_node *new=(t_node*)malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    if(!new)return 0;
    memmove(new->info,inf,siz);    !!!!!CRASH
    new->next=*p;
    *p=new;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    t_stack p;
    t_employee e={"Jhon Freeman",30000};
    createStack(&p);
    push(&p,&e,sizeof(t_employee));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memmove(new->info,inf,siz);` : `new->info` isn't uninitialized variable. You need to assign to it (allocate memory).

Comment: `struct s_nodo` --> `struct s_node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new->info is pointing to nowhere. Initialize it :)

Answer (score 1):

You declare new, but new->info is not initialized.